# Is it possible to define another preprocessor directive?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I've been looking through [code golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) and got an idea to try this code:

`#define D #define` after adding this line, everything worked fine, however I expanded it into this:

```
#define D #define
D VALUE
```

And here I got 5 compilation error. If I change `D` into `#define` everything is fine, can someone explain, why this code is illegal?

**NOTE:**  I used VS2008 compiler.

**EDIT:**  After some answers I see that I needed to give compilations error list:

1. error C2121: '#' : invalid character : possibly the result of a macro expansion
2. error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'VALUE'
3. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
4. error C2144: syntax error : 'void' should be preceded by ';'
5. error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

First error shows that `D` is not just `define` but also includes `#`.

Comment: Since it may be implementation-dependent, please state which compiler you're using.

Comment: "why this code is illegal?" - Because you can't re-define preprocessor directives.

Comment: @H2CO3 I was able to redefine it, because first time it worked, however after usage of that definition I got compilation error.

Comment: @user2623967 The C preprocessor doesn't define metasyntax.

Comment: @user2623967: No, you weren't able to redefine it. Until and unless you use a preprocessor macro, it's not expanded and therefore, not checked. In this particular case, the expansion doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Since I haven't seen this yet: "In a hypothetical world where something like this would work, it's still a really terrifically stupendously maniacally bad idea!"

Comment: @ChrisCM I know it is stupid idea, but I wanted for code golf as said before.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code is illegal because language specification says it is illegal. According to C and C++ preprocessor specification, whatever code you build using preprocessor will never be interpreted as another preprocessor directive. In short, you cannot build preprocessor directives using preprocessor. Period.

(Also, you cannot build comments using preprocessor.)

Answer (score 31):

C 2011 (N1570) 6.10.3.4 3: “The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one,…”

C++ 2010 (N3092) 16.3.4 [cpp.rescan] 3 has exactly the same text.

Comment: This is the right answer.  The C language standard specifies the exact order of operations in how the program source code is translated.

Comment: This "even if it resembles one" text goes back to the 1989 ANSI C standard (and most likely drafts before that).

Comment: N3092 isn't a standard… although the text is undoubtedly the same in C++98, C++11 and every C++ standard draft that has ever been or will ever be.

Answer (score 10):

It does look like your preprocessor is making the substitution you want, but you likely wouldn't get the behaviour you want - the preprocessor is normally just a single pass operation.  Example (with clang, but you should be able to reproduce by using the appropriate VS2008 flags):

```
$ cat example.c 
#define D #define
D VALUE
$ cc -P -E example.c 

 #define VALUE
```

That `#define VALUE` is going straight through to the compiler, which won't know what to do with it - it's a preprocessor directive, after all.  Clang's error, for reference, is similar to yours:

```
$ cc -c example.c 
example.c:2:1: error: expected identifier or '('
D VALUE
^
example.c:1:11: note: expanded from macro 'D'
#define D #define
          ^
1 error generated.
```

Comment: Whether the preprocessor is a single-pass operation or not is irrelevant. The preprocessor would not need to do more than one scan of the file in order to reprocess individual lines; it could merely process each line as many times as necessary. In fact, it does do this: Macro replacement is performed repeatedly. The reason preprocessor directives are not processed after macro replacement is because the language standard says not to.

Comment: Yup, agreed.  Didn't know about the official rules.

Answer (score 6):

That won't work because preprocessing is performed in a single pass. For example, consider the next code :

```
#define MYDEFINEWEIRD #define

MYDEFINEWEIRD N 6

int main() {

  return 0;
}
```

After preprocessing, your code will looks like :

```
 #define N 6
int main() {

  return 0;
}
```

and "#define" is not a valid syntax on C or C++. Also, since the resulting preprocessor directive is not going to be processed, it won't resolve subsequent references to the "N" macro in your code.

Just for fun, you can call the preprocesor twice from the command line using g++/gcc. Consider the next code (define.cpp) :

```
#include <iostream>

#define MYDEFINEWEIRD #define
MYDEFINEWEIRD N 6

using namespace std;

int main() {
  cout << N << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Then you can do:

```
$ g++ -E define.cpp | g++ -o define -x c++ - && ./define
```

and will output:

```
6
```

Comment: "preprocessing is performed in a single pass" - no, actually it isn't - and this is **not** the reason for the error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Well, true, it does say it is a single pass operation. But it isn't, is it? `#define FOO BAR`, then `#define BAR 0`, then `return FOO;` expanded to `return 0;` for me.

Comment: Just saw @Eric Postpischil answer, didn't know about that. I saw the preprocessed file and it looks like a single pass :-p

Comment: The C language is described as being processed in multiple translation phases, some four of those or thereabouts being preprocessing. These could be separate passes or folded together.

Answer (score 1):

Lines of code in the pre-processors eyes are either pre-processor statements (And thus don't have any replacements done on them) or normal text statements (And have replacements done). You can't have one be both, so once you have 'D' be replaced it's only going to look to see if there are any more macros to replace. Since there are none, it just leaves '#define' in the C++ code as it is and then the C++ compiler will error when it sees it (Since '#define' isn't valid C++ code).

So show my point more, this is invalid code for the pre-processor:

```
#define D define
#D value
```

Because the pre-processor doesn't do any macro replacement on pre-processor statements, and "#D" isn't a recognized pre-processor command. And this:

```
#define D #define
D value
```

Results in this C++ code:

```
#define value
```

Which is invalid because the pre-processor is already done being run.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the grammar in 16 [cpp] paragraph 1, a *replacement-list* consists of *pp-tokens* which may include the production *# no-directive* which is described in paragraph 2 of the same paragraph as

> A non-directive shall not begin with any of the directive names appearing in the list.

That is, something of the form

```
#define NAME # define
```

happens to be illegal! Also note that the `#` in this context does **not** turn the next word into a string: the quoting following a `#` only happens shen the `#` is immediately followed by a macro parameter name in a function-style macro.

Comment: The `non-directive` grammar symbol in the sentence “A non-directive shall not begin…” refers to a line `# non-directive`. Thus, it is merely distinguishing lines that look like `# some-directive` from lines that look like `# non-directive`. This does not make `#define NAME # define` an invalid preprocessor token sequence.